# LibGDX Particle Effect Color Resolution Different

Tags: libgdx

I hope to make a aurora looks like background with particle effect. Why the color effect seems so different at both desktop an real phone device view?

Desktop view

[image: Desktop view]

Phone view

[image: Phone View]

I want a smooth color like desktop view in smartphone device too. How can i achieve that? Please provide me some guideline.

My android launcher class goes as below:

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements Facebook230918 {
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    config.a = 8;
    config.b = 8;
    config.g = 8;
    config.r = 8;
    initialize(new MyGdxGame(this), config);
}
```

Comment: Specify 8888 for rgba in the application configuration.

Comment: Thank you for the guideline. May I have a more details on where to open application configuration to set rgba? I can't find any guideline on setting rgba.

Comment: Search for AndroidApplicationConfiguration to get details about it.

Comment: Thank you so much. However, the outcomes is still the same. Can i know am i setting anything wrong?

In my game class:


`AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
  
  cfg.r = 8;
  cfg.g = 8;
  cfg.b = 8;
  cfg.a = 8;`

Comment: Can you show your launcher class?

Comment: I have updated the codes into my question. Please have a read.

Comment: Hmm. Is this a low end or very old device? Maybe it doesn't support 32 bit color in OpenGL. You could enable dithering to improve the image.

Comment: I am using KitKat version (android 4.4.4 ). Thank you for providing the suggestions. Will try on newer device for a test on this issues. By the way do you think the parameter setting in particle effect editor will give this problem?